# Swift + Firebase: Getting entry by key (id): Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase database I have the following Structure

```
-Questions
--Food
--- 0
----- question
----- Answer
--- 1
----- question
----- Answer
--- 2
----- question
----- Answer
--- 5
----- question
----- Answer
--- 8
----- question
----- Answer
--- 12
----- question
----- Answer
--Comedy
--Science
--Maths
```

As you can see, there are several questions and answers that are stored under a node id, under a category. I am getting the snapshot for a specific id like so:

```
let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Questions").child(category).child(questionID)
queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.value)
})
```

Which gives me:

```
 Optional({
  answers =     (
    "T.S. Eliot",
    "S.L Luther",
    "S. Maguire",
    "C. Dickens"
  );
 question = "Who Wrote (Old Possums Book Of Practical Cats)?";
})
```

Now, what I want to do is to be able to grab the question and the answers and put them into variables.

I thought this this was the correct way:

```
 for item in snapshot.children {
    let question = item["question"] as? String
 }
```

However it returns the error:

> Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

How do I access the values by key in the snapshot like so

question

answers[0]

answers[1]

answers[2]

answers[3]

so that I can individually add them to variables?

Thank in advance.

## Update:

I have tried:

```
 if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let question = dict["question"] as? String {
      print("Question is: \(question)")
 }
```

Which outputs:

> Question is: Who Wrote (Old Possums Book Of Practical Cats)?

However, when I try and use this way to get the possible answers:

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let question = dict["question"] as? String, let answers = dict["answers"] as? String {
    print("Question is: \(question) and answers are\(answers)")
}
```

There is no output as all.

Comment: Have you checked the answers in the *Related* column? Already the first one looks pretty promising.

Comment: @vadian - I was currently using one of those. It did kind of work. Please see updated original answer.